# Best way to declare value in Kotlin class : in Constructor, body or init{}

Tags: android, class, kotlin, init

I wonder what would be the best approach for declaring values of a class in Kotlin (not necessarily in terms of performance, but also in terms of standards).
Let me explain with code, here is the 3 possibilities I see :

```
private class Player(val editText: EditText, val state: Int, val name: String = editText.text.toString().trim()) {
    init{
        //we do some code here that read the String 'name'
    }
    //some other methods
}

private class Player(val editText: EditText, val state: Int) {
    val name: String = editText.text.toString().trim()
    init{
        //we do some code here that read the String 'name'
    }
    //some other methods
}

private class Player(val editText: EditText, val state: Int) {
    init{
        val name: String = editText.text.toString().trim()
        //we do some code here that read the String 'name'
    }
    //some other methods
}
```

I absolutely want to access the names of the players by calling their getter (player1.name for example). Which one is better than the other and why ? (Perfomances and standards)

Comment: It depends on your use case. init block will execute irrespective of which constructor you call. So if you want the value to be assigned on every constructor call, go ahead and declare it in init block. If you want it specific to constructor then constructor body is best place. Also we should not pass the view to constructor, Doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: OK thanks. I needed the view because if `name.length() == 0` I use a `editText.error = "Cannot be empty!"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a distinct difference between your first option and the other two.

**Option 1 - Constructor initialization:**

This option, in addition to setting the "name" property automatically, also lets the creator of the object set the name via:

```kotlin
val myPlayer = Player(EditText(), 0, "Bob")
```

The other options don't allow the caller to set the name.

**Option 2** and **Option 3** are nearly the same, functionally. There should not be any noticeable performance differences. The biggest difference is that the code in option 2 will run before the init block.

As far as standards go:

- Pick option 1 if you want the caller to be able to set the name
- Pick option 2 if you want the name to be forced to use the "editText" object to be set

There are no hard standards, so if option 3 looks better to you and any others who will read the code, go ahead and pick that. Personally, I would only initialize fields in the init block if the initialization required code that was more complex than a basic one-liner.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! One more question : after instantiate a Player(), can I get the name of the player using `player.name` with both 3 options? If yes I think I'll choose option because : you cannot change the name with the constructor, and can see better that Player objects have a value.

Comment: *I'll choose option 2 and it also avoids overloading.

Comment: @TheBigBadBoy Yes, with all 3 options, you can access the name via the ``name`` property on the object.